# Smart bit encoding of floating point values (float, double)

Tags: encoding, floating-point

Assume I have an array of floating point values and it is currently my bottleneck in disk loading and package size limit. How do I encode those values in order to reduce data size, given the following 3 inputs:

- **Absolute error:** I can remove any mantissa bits as long as the final value is not different by real value by this amount (this come by design, it is based on screen error for visualization of data)
- **Minimum floating point value:** the smallest value in the array
- **Maximum floating point value:** the biggest value in the array

**Note:** If the float value is too small it will be just converted to a 0 (because whole mantissa is removed due to the usage of an absolute error, for too big numbers mantissa is just left untouched).

The order in which floating points values appear is important (it is NOT just a points cloud). So whichever the encoding is, after decoding the order should be preserved.

Right now I was not able to successfully save as many bits as possible:

I could save from 3 to 5 bits in the exponent field using the Min/Max values, but I was not able to exploit the absolute error, nor to exploit the extra bits in Min/Max values.
Also I can cut from 1 to 3 mantissa bits if the Max value is not too big, but here again I'm not optimally using the 3 inputs.

I'm not looking for a compression, just for a better encoding (the package is already 7-zipped). Also note I'm referring to regular float and double values, the one you can find in C# and C++.

**Importante notice:**
When exponent is big enough in IEEE floating point numbers the absolute error becomes bigger than what I use as input (first point in bullet list). This is not a problem since anyway that data started and ended as floating point. What is important instead is dropping useless bits in mantissa.

I Already tried fixed point numbers, they work, but only up to a certain degree.(see comment to tera's answer).

Comment: Why not consider custom compression tailored to the data at hand, or possibly *combined* with general-purpose compression like ZIP. Maybe have a look at: Martin Burtscher and Paruj Ratanaworabhan, "FPC: A High-Speed Compressor for Double-Precision Floating-Point Data", *IEEE Trans. Comp., Vol. 58, No. 1, Jan. 2009, pp. 18-31.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me as if you are looking for a [fixed-point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). Subtract the minimum value, divide by two times the absolute error limit, and round to nearest integer.

Comment: If I divide a 4096 space in 2^24 parts, the error I get is 0,00024, which is already lower than what I currently have good and saved 8 bits. However for certain "edge" cases like a space 2^14 divided in 2^28 parts I save more bits with the raw result above mentioned and I have more precision. Fixed precision works but only in some cases. Looking forward a better solution (implicitly, for certain Numbers a IEEE float cannot grant an asbolute error smaller than what required, sorry I had to mention that,)

Comment: That is because even a full single precision number doesn't have the precision to accurately divide the space into 2^28 parts. In this case you could enumerate all values of the fixed point representation that single precision floating point values can get mapped on. It may be worth however looking at whether your calculation actually achieves the accuracy you are after.

Comment: The problem with fixed point is that big numbers can't be represented without sacrificing lower bits and thus losing much precision where needed. However you gave me the idea to store exponents in a separate array, that may help. I'll let you know :)

Comment: "The problem with fixed point is that big numbers can't be represented without sacrificing lower bits" - that is actually a property of floating point numbers (with fixed mantissa size), not fixed point numbers.

Comment: My statement is still true XD. 1 trillion would require 39/40 bits in fixed point if I sacrifice all decimal places. But it requires much more If I want to preserve decimal places. If I already have 4 decimal places and I want to use 24 bits at most, you will see the biggest number I can have in fixed point is not so big. I know we both know how float and fixed point works XD Just guess we did not communicate that properly to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically storing vertex position data for a large mesh, there are some other dirty tricks you can employ. Which tricks work best really depends on the types of vertex clouds you'll be encountering.

One simple trick I've seen for level data (doctors hate him!) is to partition vertices by their sign and exponent. For instance, you'd have a bin specifically for +x, -y, +z vertices with exponents of 138, 140, and 131 respectively. Then you store the signs and exponents for the run (27 bits), the number of vertices in the run, and the mantissa triple for each (69 bits). The compression rate here isn't amazing, but it's an easy method to implement.

Similarly, you can store runs of nearby vertices, and use Golomb-Rice coding to specify the deltas between each pair. This is more complicated, and requires careful tuning and clustering, but can potentially produce extremely good compression ratios.

Answer (score -1):

If you care about absolute error, as opposed to relative error, you should not be using floating point numbers. Floating point is terrible at bounding absolute error; at high magnitudes it fails to achieve the needed bound, and at low magnitude it wastes its bits on precision you don't care about.

You say that in fixed point "big numbers can't be represented without sacrificing lower bits", but that has nothing to do with fixed versus floating point. If you have n bits, and require a maximum absolute error of ε, you will never be able to represent a magnitude range greater than ε*2^(n+1). But if you use floating point numbers, that n will be smaller, because you're spending bits on exponent instead of mantissa. That can never expand your magnitude range without violating your error bounds.

If you have an absolute range, and an absolute error bound, and are concerned with representation as opposed to computation, fixed-point is objectively the best you can do. If you think floating point has advantages over fixed point in this particular situiaton.

Oh, and note that all of that applies even if you've already lost precision from computation in an intermediate floating point storage. If you've violated your error bounds purely from that, then obviously it's the computation that needs to be fixed. Otherwise, the values you get out are better stored as fixed point than floating point.

Comment: totally off topic, your last paragraph is exactly what I already wrote in different words in my last 2 paragraphs. While I cannot explain fully the domain application I thought posting requisites was enough. The problem is that floating point don't works at all because range of magnitudes is too big, what yields a bigger error? a floating point which smallest mantissa bit is bigger than absolute error, or a fixed point value that is just out of fixed point range of possible values? ;) I swear the bigger error is with fixed point. I had to accept a compromise.

Comment: By the way it is visualization of 3D data, so: if data is modelled near the origin I have to use an error small enough to stay within a pixel of error. If data is far enough, that does not matter because even if the floating point resolution is bigger than a single pixel error, the 3D model is already "correct" (just because a 3D modeler placed a vertex in that position that means the position is ok to the artist, regardless if that is above or not a single pixel of error in position). Instead for data near origin a single pixel of error become extremely noticeable. I just drop useless bits.

Comment: @DarioOO It sounds, then, like you actually want to bound relative error, rather than absolute error?